# Bulk insert 0 rows inserted

Tags: sql

Im trying to use the following statement in SQL to insert data from csv to SQL..

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(A bigint,
B smallint,
C real,
D real,
E real,
F real,
G real,
H real,
I real,
J real,
K real,
L real,
M real,
N real,
O real,
P real,
Q varchar(MAX),
R varchar(MAX))

BULK INSERT Test
FROM 'C:\DataFiles\Tests.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   FIRSTROW = 2 )
```

My data looks like:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R"
"900010000000257","46","580.29","1912.31","237.73","841.41",,,"253.35","995.30","225.38","2808.70","1536.87","2250.60","1628.19","111.91",,
"900010000000425","46","1580.29","1912.31","252.34","2557.97",,,"1256.35","195.30","225.38","208.70","1534.50","222.80","1628.19","284.23",,
"900010000000841","21","489.26","5462.95","6419.69","7353.56",,,"467.70","535.01","597.93","530.84","5243.47","589.86","5790.72","6794.30",,
"900010000000990","19","4880.14","5609.45","6586.67","7470.17",,,"480.14","523.12","558.16","655.44","504.21","609.54","639.31","735.34",,
```

I get the message 0 rows affected with no errors.. Please help.

Comment: You should provide a path for that csv.

Comment: I have provided full path to csv

Comment: well update your question then, with the full path you provided

Comment: I dont know if sql server does the conversion but you are importing text into real data type.

Comment: I think it does.. I have successfully imported data for other files.. In this case Im not sure why is it not importing any data..

Comment: 18 columns and 17 values in you csv if I`m not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the full specified path like `C:\path.csv`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should not have column names in data file.